# Optimization problem on simplex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Let $  \Delta_2 = \left\lbrace \boldsymbol{\pi} \in \mathbb{R}^{3} | \; \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3\}: \, \pi_i \geq 0, \, \sum_{i = 1}^{3} \pi_i = 1     \right\rbrace $ denote the standard 2-Simplex. Now, I want to find all extreme points when I constraint my $\pi_i$ for all $i \in \{1,2,3\}$, e.g.: $\; 0.2 \leq \pi_1 \leq 0.8,\; 0.4 \leq \pi_2 \leq 1,\; 0.1 \leq \pi_3 \leq 0.9$.

Help how to approach such a problem is very much appreciated!

Comment: Consider plotting in barycentric coordinates.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for your comment. I know how to solve it graphically with barycentric coordinates, but I was just wondering if there is no "easy" analytical solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equality constraint to eliminate $\pi_3$, yielding $6$ inequality constraints ($3$ pairs of parallel inequalities).  Then consider two constraints at a time, treating them as equalities.  Each intersection yields an extreme point $(\pi_1,\pi_2)$, which you can complete to $(\pi_1,\pi_2,1-\pi_1-\pi_2)$.